# Grid texture over button

Tags: html, css

I have

```css
.grid-texture {
  background-size: 4px 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) 4px), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) 4px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-texture"></div>
<div class="btn">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

And I got this:

[image: result]

So, button becomes unavailable for use.

And now question: How do I make it so that I can push the button through the grid-texture?

OR

How to "overlay" the grid texture on top of all html elements, while maintaining the functionality of buttonsa and etc?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to `grid-texture`

```css
.grid-texture {
  background-size: 4px 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) 4px), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) 4px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-texture"></div>
<div class="btn">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add z-index & background-color:transparent; to button css.

```css
.grid-texture {
  background-size: 4px 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) 4px), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) 4px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index:9;
background-color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-texture"></div>
<div class="btn">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It will make `.btn` appear on top of grid and grid will not overlay this button.

Comment: @ciekals11 oh yes... I added background-color:transparent; too

Comment: Good answer, but answer with pointer-events in my situation, it is more suitable.